Electron Forge App: Issues with Executable File Location in Release Build
I have an Electron Forge application designed to launch a Django server (on Windows). The Django server is compiled into an executable file using PyInstaller. The Electron Forge application invokes this executable file via the spawn command.
When I build the Electron Forge application using npm run make, the application functions as expected. However, when using npm run release (which generates a setup file), the executable file cannot be located. Additionally, it does not exist in the resource folder.
I get the error when starting the server:
Error: spawn C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\****\resources\django-server\server.exe ENOENT

My forge.config.ts file:
Const config: ForgeConfig = { 
    packagerConfig: {
        asar:true,
        icon "./src/assets/Logo/icon"
        extraResources: ['./django-server/server.exe'] 
    }
    makers: [
        new MakerSquirrel({noMsi: false}),
        new MakerZIP({})
    ], ....

The server.exe file is started inside the index.ts file by using spawn:
exePath = path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'django-server', 'server.exe');
const child = spawn(exePath, []);

Why is the server.exe file not being copied to the resource folder when running npm run release ?

The issue was that the configuration of electron-forge and electron-builder was not correct. Electron-forge was used for npm run make and it works well. The release part was build with the electron-builder and this configuration was wrong.
To embed the icons and the server.exe file into the electron app, these resources had to be specified in the package.json file.
"build": {
  "win": { 
    "icon": icon "src/assets/Logo/icon",
    "extraResources": ["django-server/server.exe"]
   }
  } 

